# Finding recurrence and an algorithm to represent it

Tags: algorithms, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, intuition

> You find yourself in a country with integer coin denominations $c_1 < c_2 < ... < c_r$, where $c_1 = 1$.  Unfortunately, the greedy
>   algorithm is not guaranteed to find the optimal way to make change. 
>   Let $C(i)$ be the minimum number of coins needed to make change for
>   $i$ cents.
>
> (a) Find a recurrence for $C$.
>
> (b) Write an algorithm for computing an array OPT$[0...n]$ where
>   OPT$[i]$$ = C(i)$.

I'm not really sure how to go about doing this.  What does the information about the greedy algorithm tell us about the behavior of the problem?  How can we use the information given to write a recurrence for $C(i)$?

Comment: The information about the greedy algorithm basically just tells you how *not* to approach the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It is a typical problem in Dynamic Programming. You can check [Dynamic Programming Solution to the Coin Changing Problem](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/jaa/CSG713.04F/Information/Handouts/dyn_prog.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

By way of enrichment here is a solution in Perl that checks its arguments very carefully and otherwise tries to keep it simple. Here is a sample run for a common choice of denominations:

```
$ ./change.pl 100 1 2 5 10 20 50
1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 1, 2, 
2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 2, 3, 3, 
4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 2, 3, 3, 4, 
4, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 
4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 2
```

And this is the code.

```
#! /usr/bin/perl -w
#

MAIN: {
    my $n = shift;
    die "first argument is max value" 
        if !defined($n);
    die "positive integer please: $n"
        if $n !~ /^\d+$/ || $n < 1;

    my @denoms = ();

    while(my $denom = shift){
        die "not a positive number: $denom" if $denom !~ /^\d+$/;
        die "zero denomination: $denom" if $denom == 0; 
        die "not in order/duplicate: $denom" 
            if scalar(@denoms)>0 && $denom <= $denoms[-1];

        push @denoms, $denom;
    }

    die "no denominations" if scalar(@denoms) == 0;

    my @OPT = 
        ((undef) x ($n > $denoms[-1] ? $n : $denoms[-1])); 
    unshift @OPT, 0;
    foreach my $denom (@denoms) { $OPT[$denom] = 1 };

    for(my $val = 1; $val < scalar(@OPT); $val++){
        my $choice = $OPT[$val];

        foreach my $try (@denoms) {
            my $prev = $val - $try;
            last if $prev < 0;

            my $count = $OPT[$prev];
            if(defined($count)){
                if(!defined($choice) || $count+1 < $choice){
                    $choice = $count + 1;
                }
            }
        }

        $OPT[$val] = $choice if defined($choice);
    }
    shift @OPT;

    print join ', ', map {defined($_) ? $_ : 'X'} @OPT;
    print "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you are making change amount $Z$ and you can't do it with only one coin.  Then $Z = X + Y$, and you've already calculated the optimum amount for $X$ and $Y$.   So just check all possible $X$ and $Y$ pairs.